# karate UI webSockets : getting invalid handshake response getStatus: 403 Forbidden

Tags: websocket, karate

A day back my scripts were working just fine,but all of a sudden I started getting this error when I launched the scripts today.Can someone help me with this ?

[main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - driver config / start failed: io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 403 Forbidden, options: {type=chrome, target=null}
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 403 Forbidden

Additionally I cam across this similar question,but it didn't gave a clear direction.
[karate webSockets : getting invalid handshake response getStatus: 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73501411/karate-websockets-getting-invalid-handshake-response-getstatus-403-forbidden)

Comment: the only way to get a clear direction is help others simulate the problem as mentioned in the comments on the question you linked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is the exact issue which i was facing.The solution provide here did help me resolve it.  https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2275

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this in the driver settings addOptions: ["--remote-allow-origins=*"]

For example:

- configure driver = { type: 'chrome', addOptions: ["--remote-allow-origins=*"] }